# cast dropdownlist datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

is there a way to cast the DropDownlist datasource to a data table.

following is possible for gridview. but not for dropdownlist.

```
DataTable dtSource = (DataTable)DropDownListCNPPRO.DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSource` property is just a getter and setter methods for a internal variable. Judging on the question content, I am guessing that property is some kind of IDataSource type, which is implemented with `DataTable` class.

But, my point is, you can cast some property some other to type `T` **if and only if**:

- `T` is the base class or interface for that property.
  **or**
- `T` is not the base class, but an heir, and it or it's descendants **was set** to that property before. Like this:

#### Example

```
interface IFoo { }
class Foo1 : IFoo { }
class Foo2 : IFoo { }

class Bar
{
    internal IFoo Foobar { get; set; }
}

void main()
{
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.Foobar = new Foo1();

    IFoo instance1 = bar.Foobar; // Ok.
    Foo1 instance2 = (Foo1)bar.Foobar; // Bad practice, but ok.

    Foo2 instance3 = (Foo2)bar.Foobar; // Bad practive plus an exception.
    Foo2 instance3 = (Foo2)(Foo1)bar.Foobar; // Still an exception.
    Foo2 instance3 = (Foo2)(IFoo)(Foo1)bar.Foobar; // Still a fail.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely depends on what the datasource is. If you replace

```
DropDownListCNPPRO.DataSource
```

by the "real" datasource (e.g. a generic list), the compiler will tell you if you can convert or not.